# how to put all object files to the directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a Makefile wihich produces so many object file - .o - . How can I redirect those to the one directory then create an executable from this directory ?

```
 Makefile format :

 x.o = x.hpp x.cpp
      g++ -c x.cpp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that seems to be easy:

```
app: bin/x.o
    g++ bin/x.o -obin/x

bin/x.o: x.cpp
    g++ -c x.cpp -obin/x.o
```

You need to create the bin directory, but you can also add that to the Makefile easily.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `-o` option of g++, it should also work when creating only the object file, e.g.:

```
g++ -c x.cpp -o objdir/x.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rule like this:

```
%.o: %.cpp $(HPP_FILES) Makefile
        $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -c -o directory/$@ $<
```

Then link all files there using something like:

```
my_binary: $(OBJ_FILES)
        $(CC) $(LD_FLAGS) -o $@ directory/$(OBJ_FILES)
```

You can define OBJ_FILES, HPP_FILES using simple assignment like:
HPP_FILES := x.hpp y.hpp etc.